# Subclassing UISearchDisplayController For Abstraction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have multiple `UIViewController` that have table views.  I want these VCs to just handle UI stuff as they will all search the same database.  I want to subclass `UISearchDisplayController` so I can have this subclass handle all the data and search stuff.

The VC I am working with is a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` and a `UISearchDisplayController`.  I have it set and can check to display the initial, or the searched data into the table view by using if/else statements like: `if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) % else...`

I want this custom subclass that I'm creating to handle the code that is executed in the `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView` statement so I can have some abstraction and can use this custom class with other VCs.

Any ideas on how to continue with this?  I think I need to override some methods in the `UISearchDisplayController`.

EDIT:

Actually I may be coming into this wrong. I have it stepup the way I like right now, but there is no abstraction, so I can't really reuse this code in other parts of the app.  My IB is setup like this: [image]